# Choosing Google App Engine Standard vs Flexible Environment for Laravel Application?

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel

I am deploying a Laravel app (content management system) on GCP App Engine but I am not sure what are the advantages or disadvantages of standard vs flexible environment and how it would impact a Laravel application. The application will not have many users (low traffic) but will require to read the database and show outputs etc. for a number of rows. Could someone please highlight differences and provide suggestions. I am sorry if this question doesn't fit here as I am new to this StackExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s a great question. Both environments have their pros and cons, and at the end of the day, you’ll decide what best suits your needs.

### App Engine Standard

**TL;DR:** Super fast startup, scales to zero, priced by the number of instance hours somewhat restrictive

**Pros:**

- The app can scale to zero when it is idle
- Deploys quickly
- Autoscales in seconds
- Can run for free or at very little cost

**Cons:**

- Only specific languages are supported
- No Background processes
- Can’t consume VM resources
- No flexibility in the runtime
- No SSH

### App Engine Flex

**TL;DR:** Super customizable and high performing environment at the cost of scalability overhead and cost

**Pros:**

- Everything is customizable. Runtime and Infrastructure
- Instances can be accessed via SSH, unlocking more potential
- Performance is SOLID as it runs on the VMs that suit your needs. Background processes and thread exist

**Cons:**

- Does not scale to 0. You need to have 1 instance at all times
- Takes significantly longer to deploy
- Scaling instance takes longer
- Costs a more than standard

### Takeaway

Use App Engine Standard if you don’t need to customize the runtime or infrastructure.

In your case, I would suggest you use App Engine Standard as your app isn’t going to have many users and you can [connect to Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard).

I hope that this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, my current setup is GAE standard with Cloud SQL. I tried Flex for a day but it got very expensive in comparison. I think I will stick to standard considering there will be significant idle time.